# How to use hook control an array

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I wanna make an array controled by hook
It looks like this

```
 const [reasons, setReasons] = useState([false, false, false, false]);
```

How could I switch each boolean with setReasons

if I do like this

```
 onPress={() =>
        handleReasons(reasons, setReasons, number)
      }

  const handleReasons = (checked, setChecked, number) => {
    setReasons([
      ,
      {
        id: number,
        value: !reasons,
      },
    ]);
  };
```

its just not working

and if I change hook like this

```
 const [reasons, setReasons] = useState([]);
```

when I call handleReasons,it just add new item in array instead of update reasons[number] value

```
const handleReasons = (checked, setChecked, number) => {
    setChecked([!checked[number]]);
  };
```

I change the code like this

it works for reasons[0]
but it cant control others in array.

Comment: it adds a new item because that's what you're assigning to it with `[...reason, ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You just set array again with new value, that what i do when i update array value. You can `console.log` value to see updated may be view not reRender so just call view render again or set key of view with data of them

  ```
  <View key="(id) (value)" >Row data<View>
  ```

  Code example

  ```
  const handleReasons = (id, newValue) => {
    let updateArray = reasons;

    for (let i = 0; i < updateArray.length; i++) {
      let item = updateArray[i];
      if (item.id === id) {
        item.value = newValue;
        break;
      }
    }
    setReasons(updateArray);
  };
  ```